# using files to write to record and view it in c

Tags: c, arrays, file, struct

I'm having a problem and running short on time so ill try to make it concise as possible.

I'm trying to build an ATM system in visual studio 2010(its a requirement so i have to). I'm at a point where i have to use files to record information of the people who use the ATM(including the involvement of structures). What I'm trying to do here is try to get the file to work(i.e write and read).

The Structure:

```
struct studentA
{
int nip;
double Accn;
int money;
int damount;
int saccount;
};
```

The Function To Write to file:(I believe the section is working properly)

```
    int r;
FILE *fpro2;
struct studentA e={0,0,1000,0,0};
fpro2=fopen("Slr.txt","wb");
if(fpro2==NULL)
 {
     puts("Can't open that file!");
     exit(1);
 }
for(r=1000;r<=2000;++r)
{
    fwrite(&e,1, sizeof(e),fpro2);
}

printf("Enter Account Number(Between 1000-2000):");
scanf("%d", &e.Accn);

fseek(fpro2, sizeof(e)*(e.Accn-1), SEEK_SET);
fwrite(&e,1, sizeof(e), fpro2);
fclose(fpro2);

printf("This File has been Updated");

getch();
system("cls");
menumain();

    }
```

The Function to Read from File:
(I believe this is where the error resides but I'm unsure on how to solve it)

```
    void tlog()
    {
FILE *fpro2;
struct studentA e={0,0,1000,0,0};
fpro2=fopen("Slr.txt","rb");

if(fpro2 !=NULL)
{
    fseek(fpro2, sizeof(e)*(e.Accn-1), SEEK_SET);
    fread(&e,1, sizeof(e), fpro2);
    fclose(fpro2);

    if(e.Accn !=0)
        {
        printf("Student Records\n");
        printf("Account: %d\n", e.Accn);
        }
    else
        printf("No Records To Recover...Sry\n");
}
else
    printf("Could not Open Siar");

getch();
menumain();
    }
```

---

The problems that usually arises would be that I get "No Records to Recover...Sry"

Prior to this however the declaration of e.Accn was "%s" and what had happened was that when i called "tlog" it would print numbers but not what was entered. example i entered 1211 and got back 82901232 or something close to that. Any help would be appreciated thanks.

### UPDATE

changed Accn in the structure from double to int, 
changed Accn scanf and printf from %d to %i, 
changed Accn in the fseek area from e.Accn-1 to e.Accn+1

Comment: Why are you using a `double` for the account-number? I've never seen a floating-point account number.

Comment: //Making account numbers double was just out of sheer frustration in order to see something change

Comment: @AtlasB Change format to `printf("Account: %lf\n", e.Accn);`

Comment: @chux it doesn't show any effect, i used it in tlog but it still just gave the else statement

Answer (score 3):

One of the problems here is not quite what you think it is: If you read e.g. [this `scanf` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) you will see that the format `"%d"` is for *integers*. That means it will read an integer and write it to a `double` variable. The bit-pattern for an integer is not the same as a `double`.

Another problem is that when you read the accounts, you use `e.Accn-1` in your `fseek` call. But what is the value of `e.Accn` at that point? It's *zero* so you try to seek to a negative position.

Comment: Much appreciated for responding, i have changed "Accn" to int in the struct. The goal of this section is to create 2000 records but only the latter 1000 will be used so I'm assuming, with what you pointed i should change e.Accn-1 to e.Accn+1(which i did). Doing these changes however hasn't changed the outcome much.